# matlab histogram (with for loops)

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

I'm doing an exercise where I have to plot the histogram of an image by reading each pixel's value. Then my idea is to loop through each color layers (r, g, b) and for each pixel store the value in a matrix. The following code runs but there it doesn't look right and I'm not totally sure why. First issue is that the graph is not a histogram with vertical bars and stacked values (How can I achieve that) and the second issue is that the graph is weird as it looks like the same values are applied for r, g and b, which is not possible given the images I'm using. Help? Thanks!

```
clc;
clear;

%% init values

% loading initial image
init_img = imread('face-1.jpg');

% rgb matrixes
r = zeros(256, 1);
g = zeros(256, 1);
b = zeros(256, 1);

%% main loop

% for each colour (r-g-b)
for a = 1:size(init_img, 3)

    % loop through eache layer of the image
    for i = 1:size(init_img, 1)
        for j = 1:size(init_img, 2)

           if(a == 1)
               for n = 1:size(r,1)
                if(n == init_img(i, j, 1))
                    % get value (x) from n(th) row, column 1
                    x = r(n, 1);                    
                    r(n, 1) = x+1;
                end
               end
           elseif(a == 2)
               for n = 1:size(g,1)
                if(init_img(i, j, 1) == n-1)
                    % get value (x) from n(th) row, column 1
                    x = g(n, 1);                    
                    g(n, 1) = x+1;
                end
               end
           elseif (a == 3)
               for n = 1:size(b,1)
                if(init_img(i, j, 1) == n-1)
                    % get value (x) from n(th) row, column 1
                    x = b(n, 1);                    
                    b(n, 1) = x+1;
                end
               end
           end          
        end
    end
end

%% plot

plot(r, 'Red');
hold('on');
plot(g, 'Green');
hold('on');
plot(b, 'Blue');
```

[image: histogram]

Comment: why don't you just use the hist function on the image?

Comment: You're not plotting histograms, you're using the plot function which just plots individual points. Use hist or bar to get the graphs you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this helps:

I changed your code a little bit and came up with the following. 
I retrieve the pixel value by iterating through the image and store it in the corresponding bin. Instead of `plot` I'm using `bar` (see [here](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html))

```
% loading initial image
init_img = imread('test.jpg');

% rgb matrixes
r = zeros(256, 1);
g = zeros(256, 1);
b = zeros(256, 1);

%% main loop

for i = 1:size(init_img, 1)
   for j = 1:size(init_img,2)
       pix = init_img(i,j,1:3);

       r(pix(1)+1) = r(pix(1)+1) + 1;
       g(pix(2)+1) = g(pix(2)+1) + 1;
       b(pix(3)+1) = b(pix(3)+1) + 1;
   end
end

%% plot
subplot(2,1,1);
title('histogram using for loops');
hold('on');
bar(r);
bar(g);
bar(b);

%% compare data
subplot(2,1,2);
title('imhist');
hold('on');
imhist(init_img(:,:,1));
imhist(init_img(:,:,2));
imhist(init_img(:,:,3));
```

I added a compare section in the end which uses `imhist` (see [here](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html) for documentation).
If this doesn't suite your requirements take a look at `histogram` ([here](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html)).

The script will print the following (note that the color in the plots does not match the corresponding color of the pixels):

[image: comparison]

Comment: Hi, your solution lookes great! I'm still new to matlab and a bit confused on how to handle matrixes. Just one thing, I tried the code but I don't get the 3 different colours. What could the reason be? I've attached the image. Thanks!

Comment: that is interesting. have you checked that all color arrays (e.g. `r`) are filled? and also make sure that you use `hold on`. In any case you could try to specify the color in the plot e.g. `bar(r,'r')` for red

Comment: that made it..by default all colors were set to be the same..I've specified them and not it looks ok..thanks! I do have a final question..can you clarify the +1 in the lines: r(pix(1)+1) ?

Comment: great! I guessed that the pixel values range from 0 to 255. however, matlab matrices are indexed starting from 1. That is why I simple did `pix(1)+1` to shift the range  to 1 to 256. The last +1 in the line is to increase the bucket count.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the first plane of `init_img` three times! You should read `init_img(i,j,a)` instead.

Other than that:
- Why the loop over a if you are doing something different for each a? Might as well remove the loop and the conditionals.
- Dont loop over n. You can directly set `n=init_img(i,j,a)`.